# Regex to match last occurrence

Tags: ruby, regex

as i don't want to spend another hour googling forthe right regex: I want to remove the last backslash of a given string with gsub:

```
"C:\Program Files\".gsub(fancy_regex_here, '') # => "C:\Program Files"
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

fancy_regex_here should be `"\\$"`

Comment: Right. Thats what the requirement seems although not specifically mentioned.

Comment: Argh, so easy. Thanks a lot :-)